# Excel formula to split cell text based on char count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently around 500 chars in my cell and i would like to split anything over 255 chars into the next cell. The below just duplicates the cell value if over 255 chars and does not split it.

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>255,A1,"")
```

Don't want to use the UI split text feature as i need to run multiple times and its so time consuming.

Appreciate any assistance.

Cheers~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the cell with you text is **`A1`**, then:

- ...in the cell that you want the first 255 characters, you'd use formula:

  ```
  =LEFT(A1,255)
  ```
- ...in the cell that you want the remaining characters, if any, use formula:

  ```
  =IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-255),"")
  ```

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Text Functions** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-functions-reference-cccd86ad-547d-4ea9-a065-7bb697c2a56e)
- Office.com : [**`LEFT` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)
- Office.com : [**`RIGHT` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/right-function-c02a18a8-b224-437e-aaba-1b785c6c61bf)
- Office.com : [**`LEN` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb)
- Office.com : [**`IFERROR` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)

Comment: thats a simplier way of doing it. in the future i might need to worry about multiple '255' char splits - but this should work nicely for the moment. Thanks so much Ash!

Comment: @Chris When you have over 510 characters, then you'll probably want to use `MID` instead of `RIGHT`.  If you combine it with `COLUMN`, you can have 1 formula that you just drag across